# Copying Contents of Matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to copy the results to a matrix and want the output in a 32768*8 array. This is the code I am using, but it stops working after the last line.

As you can see for the first file ( i=1), the decimal data,T(32768*1) is converted to M(32768*8). Now I want this M to be stored for each iteration of i, without overwriting anything.

```
Files_list = getAllFiles('C:\Stellaris Measurements\Stellaris-LM4F120_all');
for i = 1:15000
B=num2str(cell2mat(Files_list(i)));
fid = fopen(B,'rb');
T= fread(fid,inf,'uint8','ieee-be');
total = numel(T);
%M=textread('C:\Users\admin\Workspace\STELLARIS-LM4F120_00_210214_104000_0001_temp_025.bin','%2c');
%M=dec2bin(M);
M= de2bi(T,8,'left-msb');
M = measure(i);
end
```

So, basically I want to create a martix for each of the measurement, which will store the converted binary results in a 32768*8 array.

Thanks!

BR,
\Kashif

Comment: Is **de2bi** a custom function?  What is **measure(i)**?  You are overwriting the results in **M** of whatever the **de2bi** function returned with something (**measure(i)**) that has yet to be defined...

Comment: de2bi is a matlab function for conversion of decimal to binary. Yes, the value of M would be overwritten for every iteration of i. So you can say that for every value of i, I need a matrix which is 32768*8. measure(i) is crap. i just used it for assigning the value of M for each iteration into it.

Comment: for j = 1:total
    for k = 1:8
    B(k,j,i) = M(j,k);
    end
   
end    some new lines I have added to my code but not of much avail till now. hope this helps!!

Comment: Please post the new code to the question.  Given your comments above, I'm not to make of what you have said.  The **measure** variable doesn't exist so that is why the line **M=measure(i)** is failing.  In your new code above, you now have **B** which was being used for the file name but is now a 3D matrix?